# Eclipse Juno pom editor bottom tabs not visible

Tags: eclipse, tabs, editor, pom.xml, eclipse-juno

I switched from Eclipse Indigo to Juno and I have one very irritating problem. When I open a pom editor the tabs under the main window are not visible (these with Dependency Hierarchy and so on). The same thing is when I use the JPDL editor... Is there anybody that has the same problem and knows the solution? My OS is Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm using classical Ubuntu theme. When I use the CSS spy in Eclipse, the tabs are highlited on red, but they are not showing.

Comment: Have you tried Window -> Reset Perspective

Comment: What other eclipse plugins are you using? I had this problem when I installed the Android dev tools for eclipse